# Firebase Checking if username exists

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently developing an android app that only requires the user to sign up once after pressing *start*. The next time the user opens the application, pressing *start* will redirect the user to the main game already.

I was able to do this using SharedPreferences. After signing up, I store a value called currentState and I use it to check if the user has already signed up. Here's the code:

```
   final int currentState = sharedPreferences.getInt(USERSTATE_NUM_KEY,0);
   if(currentState == 0 ) {
          Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main_Screen.class);
          startActivity(i);
    } else{
               // Redirect user to tutorial page, then the map page.
    }
```

Now I was asked to accomplish this again using Firebase since I've already stored the user data.

Here's my code so far just to try if it's going to the *onDataChange* but it doesn't and I'm not sure how to do it now. Here's my code so far:

```
final String currentUsername = sharedPreferences.getString(USERNAME_NUM_KEY, "");
final DatabaseReference userNameRef = rootReference.child("users");
startGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            userNameRef.orderByChild("username").equalTo(currentUsername)
                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                Log.v("TESTERR", "HELLO I EXIST LOL");
                            }
                            else{
                                Log.v("TESTERR", "NEW USER PAGE");
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
 }
 });
```

[image: firebase databasee]

Thank you!!!

Comment: We have an Android project that requires us to use Services. My group mate told me to do it again to further utilize the database because we're just using it now for our leaderboard page.

Comment: but why do you want to use ondatachange to check if user is logged in? Have you used firebase authentication?

Comment: actually i was just searching for how to actually check if the user already exists when the application starts. what i really need is just to check if its in the database but the only answer i could find was the one above

Comment: yes, what don't you like with the answer above?

Comment: with the new code, everytime i click start i dont think im getting the snapshot. im new to firebase and im not sure why the "datasnapshot.exists" is inside ondatachanged thats why i was trying to see if it was going to go through the method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
userNameRef.orderByChild("username").equalTo(currentUsername)
```

is a query it is like saying `where username= currentUsername`

The `currentUsername` is the logged in user, the datasnapshot is `users`.

So in your database you have:

```
users
 userid
   username: currentUsername
```

When you use `if(dataSnapshot.exists()){` it checks the snapshot which is `users` and checks the `where` condition, if theys exists in the database then it will enter the if clause.

If the `where` condition does not exists in the database then it will enter the `else`.

Comment: It's weird though because nothing shows up on my Log making me think that it doesn't really enter the method at all?

Comment: check if it is "users" and not "Users", also inside the equalTo write the name: "kanyewest" as in the database and test it